# HTML tabs with content in separate files

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

I am at the moment using this [code for HTML/JS tabs](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp). 
But the code gets way to messy since it is all in one file, is it possible to separate the code in tab one, tab two etc?

```
 <!-- Tab links -->
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript

```
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Also, at the moment it does not show which tab you are on. Ideally would be to have /#tab1, /#tab2 etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you can have one html one css and one js file and paste the codes accordingly. load both the css and js files on your html. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I might not have been clear enough. The problem is that I have all the code in one file. I want tab1.html, tab2.html etc otherwise it will get too messy.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that code is OK. So this should mean your not including your JS correctly.

I just copied your code and pasted ( I just modified the begining of the script to hide all tabcontents)

```js
var tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! The issue is that I have all the code in the same .html file. I want the code for example London in one html, the code for Paris in another html.